# Is it safe to watch a video/picture of class 4 laser?

Tags: video, laser

Was wondering because I heard they were very dangerous even if not looked at directly. Wonder if looking at a picture or video can harm eyes may sound like a will question but it's always good to be on the safe side

Comment: Normal displays cannot harm your eyes. For example, a video of the sun will not harm your eyes when played back on an LCD or computer or whatever.

Comment: The question is, can a bullet in an action movie accidentally hurt the audience.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum especially in 3D movies...

Answer (score 7):

At worst the recording device will saturate (and the camera element may be damaged), but the playback device will only generate an intensity that *it* is capable of. There is no danger to vision that would not normally be present with the playback device.

Comment: Burning out camera sensors is a fairly popular game at laser shows, we warn them but they still take pictures and moan when they wind up will a full frame sensor with a few lines of dead pixels.